# Cython- C method not previously declared in definition part of extension type

Tags: python, python-2.7, cython, cythonize

I am doing a project that needs this library (pylibol). link: https://github.com/billhhh/pylibol. When i build setup.py,it shows **C method 'get_weight' not previously declared in definition part of extension type 'SOL'**.

```
> Error compiling Cython file:
> ------------------------------------------------------------ ...
>         dict: mapping of string to string
>         """
>         params = dict()
>         sol_GetModelParameters(self._c_model, get_parameter, <void*>params)
>         return params
>     cpdef np.ndarray[float, ndim=1, mode="c"] get_weight(self, cls_id=0):
>          ^
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> 
> python/pysol.pyx:141:10: C method 'get_weight' not previously declared
> in definition part of extension type 'SOL'
```

The problem is happened in pysol.pyx. So i checked pysol.pyx and add **cdef get_weight** in pysol.pdx.

pysol.pyx:

```
def get_params(self):
        """Get Model Parameters

        Returns
        -------
        dict: mapping of string to string
        """
        params = dict()
        sol_GetModelParameters(self._c_model, get_parameter, <void*>params)
        return params
    cpdef np.ndarray[float, ndim=1, mode="c"] get_weight(self, cls_id=0):
        """Get Model Weight,
        input cls_id: the id of classifier, in range 0 to cls_num-1
        output an numpy array of classifier for the cls_id 's class.
        for binary classifier, cls_id is 0 and cls_num=1
        """
        d=sol_Getw_dime(self._c_model, cls_id)
        cdef np.ndarray[float, ndim=1, mode="c"] w = np.zeros((d,),dtype=np.float32)
        sol_Getw(self._c_model, cls_id,&w[0])
        return w
```

pysol.pdx:

```
cdef class SOL:
    cdef void* _c_model
    cdef void* _c_data_iter
    cdef const char* algo
    cdef int class_num
    cdef bint verbose
    cdef get_weight
```

But this is happened:

**AttributeError: 'PyObjectType' object has no attribute 'exception_check'**

any idea why this happened?
I'm working on ubuntu and using python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to proceed would probably be to go back to a 2017 version of Cython. It [looks like](https://github.com/billhhh/pylibol/blob/master/python/pysol.cpp#L1) it was originally built in with Cython 0.25.2.

---

If you don't want to do that then you need to look at the lines you're adding:

```
cdef get_weight
```

says that the class has an attribute called `get_weight` which is typed as a Python object (by default). Instead you want to match the function signature of `get_weight`

```
cpdef np.ndarray[float, ndim=1, mode="c"] get_weight(self, cls_id=0)
```

(I can't remember exactly what you do with default arguments off the top of my head - you may need to remove the `=0` from the .pyx file).

---

Alternatively you could just change `cpdef` to `def` in the ".pyx" files. A `def` function doesn't need declaring in advance (and in my opinion `cpdef` functions are usually the wrong choice).

Comment: Changing into Cython 0.25.2 and change cdef get_weight into cpdef get_weight doesn't work. For the last solution, do you mean like this? **def np.ndarray[float, ndim=1, mode="c"] get_weight(self, cls_id=0):** but it's still raise error.

Comment: For the last solution just do `def get_weight(self, cls_id=0)`. Don't specify the output type. If you change back to Cython 0.25.2 then you should put everything back as it originally was. It looks like an unmaintained broken package though - there may be a huge list of problems to fix before you get it working though.

Comment: Changing version to Cython 0.25.2 without changing anything in the program(using original program) or using the modified program `def get_weight(self, cls_id=0)` raised an error. Both suggession raised error **command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1** . I've tried `sudo apt-get install python-dev` but still error. is it because my g++ version? but I've fulfilled prequisites (my g++ = 10.2.0). Any idea? I'm sorry this slightly out of topic, but I badly need this library work because sadly there's no alternative library that i can use.

Comment: The "exit status 1" error tells you very little. There will be a more useful message before it that will tell you why it's failing. I doubt that your GCC version is the problem. You are making progress though - you've got further on in building it.

Comment: The only error that I see is: `In file included from src/sol/model/model.cc:9: include/sol/model/model.h:87:25: error: extra qualification ‘sol::model::Model::’ on member ‘Get’ [-fpermissive] 87 |   math::Vector<real_t>* Model::Get() const; |                         ^~~~~ ` what does it means? Aside that that there's a lot of warning. Do warnings count as clues?

Comment: That error isn't too important and is easily ignored (by passing `-fpermissive` to gcc). Edit setup.py and add `'-fpermissive'` to the list of `extra_compile_args`. The warnings won't be the reason that gcc is failing